# How to prevent PHP String truncates after 1997 characters

Tags: php

In PHP how can I store a block of text 4000 characters to a string? It currently truncates characters to a total of 1997 characters. Is there a special string that I can utilize that will hold 4000 Plus characters

Comment: PHP strings do not have this kind of character limit. The problem must be something else. Can you show us some code? (Edit your question, please.)

Comment: maybe you try to store the data in a database? database can truncate your data, it might be an issue there...

Comment: How do you know it's being truncated?  Maybe it's just how you're displaying it that's cutting it off.  What does `var_dump(strlen($string));` show you?

Answer (score 1):

Php strings don't have [limit](http://web.archive.org/web/20100612021624/http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), the only limit is the `memory_limit` directive in the php.ini configuration file. The memory limit defaults to `128MB` in PHP 5.2, and `8MB` in earlier releases. Maybe you are using a php version lower than 5.2?

> Note: It is no problem for a string to become very large. PHP imposes
>   no boundary on the size of a string ; the only limit is the available
>   memory of the computer on which PHP is running.

Answer (score 0):

as the guys mentioned, php does not have a string length limit, for php limit is is memory if you exceed memory limit, you will get error. How do you see that a sting is truncated? if it is in var_dump - most likely it can be your xdebug truncating it (change xdebug settings in php.ini to allow for longer output). If it is in a database, it could be that your DB field does not support that many characters.